# How to use wp_filter_oembed_result?

Tags: sanitization, escaping, iframe

I have a video iframe it's can be youtube , vimeo etc

```
  $iframe = get_field($field, $id);
                if(empty($iframe)){
                  return;
                }
                preg_match('/src="(.+?)"/', $iframe, $matches);
                $src = $matches[1];
                $params = array(
                    'controls' => 1,
                    'hd'       => 1,
                    'autohide' => 1,
                    'autoplay' => $set_auto,
                );
                apply_filters( 'video_parameters', $params );
                $new_src = add_query_arg($params, $src);
                $iframe  = str_replace($src, $new_src, $iframe);
                $attributes = 'frameborder="0"';
                $iframe     = str_replace('></iframe>', ' ' . $attributes . '></iframe>', $iframe);                
                echo $iframe;
```

As per documentation i have to use this  wp_filter_oembed_result() but i dont know how ..please help

Comment: To do what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JacobPeattie escape iframe generated at the last line

Comment: What, why? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JacobPeattie oh.. is it okay to echo iframes without escaping?  esc_html() wont work..